# increment value of a column if it already exists in the column using a tail in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to increment the value of a column if it exists in the column

Here is my table:

```
date           time         res
2021-03-22     10:00:01     20210322100001001
2021-03-22     10:00:02     20210322100002001
2021-03-22     10:00:02     20210322100002002 <=
2021-03-23     10:00:05     20210323100005001
```

We have a `date` column, a `time` column, and a `res` column.

The date and time are given and we need to select data for `res` in such a way that it concats date and time after removing "-" and ":" and then end with tail '001' however if the value formed exists increment the tail.

For `res` I have

```
CONCAT(REPLACE(xx.date,'-',''),REPLACE(xx.time,':',''),'001')
```

However Im not sure how to increment the tail part to 002 if there already exists same data in the column.

Also I cant change the table(add any keys, integers and such)

Ive gone through many iterations of this question but they dont quite work for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably u need to write a procedure to check for duplicate value of res and then update the res. for example if total unique rows with first two columns already present then u need to update res accordingly.

Comment: Do you want to update the table? If yes, then you need a primary key, like an id.

Comment: Yeah thatd be one way for it. However I was wondering if it could be done entirely in sql in the line itself without needing to call a procedure. Thanks for the reply tho

Comment: Hi @forpas I was actually looking for a way to see if I could text you directly. yesterday you solved another query that I had. Thanks for that one again. but no like i said I cannot change or lookup schema

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, if you want to update the table you need a column that defines the order of the rows, because tables are unordered. If you just want a SELECT query, it can be done with window functions if your version of MySql is 8.0+

Comment: @forpas Im not sure how you mean it. Can you please give a link or so that I can look through? Thanks

Comment: I mean that the way you presented your requirement it was implied that there is a column `res` in the table and you want to update this column. But since you accepted the below answer it seems that this is not so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
CONCAT(REPLACE(xx.date, '-', ''),
       REPLACE(xx.time, ':', ''),
       LPAD(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY xx.date, xx.time ORDER BY xx.time), 3, '0')
      )
```